# URL pattern in web xml and Restful path

Tags: java, rest, jetty

I have Restful service, in web.xml

< url-pattern >/*< / url-pattern >

And in my Root class,

```
@Path("")
```

I'm using embedded jetty server, and giving context path.

If I try to access the resource with

```
http://localhost:1212/context
```

Its showing error, but if I use

```
http://localhost:1212/context/
```

Its working, how to solve this, I want my target URL as

```
http://localhost:1212/context
```

I cant empty my context

Comment: i think what you are trying to achieve is to have a welcome file. am i correct?

Comment: No. Its Restful service, not such welcome files. Its a target URL for my resource.

Comment: Any clues to solve this?

Comment: No idea..you can try with urlpattern as * only.

Comment: It'll thorw exception.

Comment: Instead of `/*` try `/`. Also from a URI/URL perspective `/context` and `/context/` are different. The first might produce a directory listing whereas the last one accesses a default file.

Comment: So I cant make a target URL like this? http://localhost:1212/context

Answer (score 0):

If `context` is the root of your application `localhost:1212/context` is not a valid URL into your service resource (REST) as it has to start with `/`

Make `localhost:1212` the root of your application and `/context` your resource name. But I assume this collides with other plans you have?

You could configure nginx/apache/tomcat or similar to rewrite the url though.

Comment: Ya I finally came up with localhost:1212/context/ as my target URL, 'cause I cant make my context as empty.